# Relacionamento MORPH

Tags: laravel, modelagem

Estou modificando uma `table` do banco de dados, no caso é para ser feito um relacionamento morph dos campos que estão conforme a imagem.

Estou usando o Laravel 5.6

Como faço essa relação dentro da migration? 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Na documentação diz para fazer o Morph assim

```
$table->morphs('taggable'); Adds taggable_id UNSIGNED BIGINT and  taggable_type VARCHAR equivalent columns.
```

conforme https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations